# Location tracking in background while onChanging of the location in Android

Tags: android, location, locationmanager, locationlistener

I am developing android application using the Location. I am able to get the current location using following code.

```
  public void GetLocation()
     {
        boolean isGPSEnabled = false;
        boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;
        private LocationManager mLocationManager;
        private String mProvider;
        mLocationManager = (LocationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Criteria criteria = new Criteria();     
        isGPSEnabled = mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        isNetworkEnabled = mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
        if(isGPSEnabled && isNetworkEnabled)
        {
            mProvider = mLocationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
            Location location = mLocationManager.getLastKnownLocation(mProvider);           
            Sring mLatitude=String.valueOf(arg.getLatitude());           
            String mLongitude=String.valueOf(arg.getLongitude());            
        }
    }
```

I need to **update the location of the user in background, once the location is changed not frequently.** How can I achieve this?

Comment: By "update in the background" you mean to receive `Location` updates as the user moves, or updating the `Location` using a separate `Thread`?

Comment: I need to updated the location values in background, while the user location changes.

Comment: Choosing a best answer is not a bad option!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use location listener. You can listen the location in specific meters or specific time interval. Check [this tutorial.](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2010/09/android-location-based-services.html)

```
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(

                LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,

                **MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES**,

                **MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES**,

                new MyLocationListener()

        );
```

Comment: Shall I listen the location while changing the location instead of specific meters or time interval.

Comment: Yes you can do it. Check my update, MINIMUM_TIME_BETWEEN_UPDATES, MINIMUM_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES params.

Comment: Thanks for the update. If I am giving those two parameters as zero means, I can get the updated frequently.Am I correct? or I get the location values once the location is changed?

Comment: Thanks a lot. The onlocation change method is triggered frequently, that's fine. How can I update the location change event alone in background.? That's I need to get the location update even the app is not running.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class CurrentLatLng implements LocationListener {

    public static final int GPS_NOT_ENABLED = -1;
    public static final int VALID = 1;

    LocationManager manager;
    Context context;

    public CurrentLatLng(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    public void getCurrentLatLng() {

        //Check if GPS is enabled
        if (Commons.isGPSEnabled(context)) {
            manager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            manager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 10, 10, this);
        } else {
            // GPS NOT ENABLED. EVEN THEN THE LOCATION WILL BE RECIEVED AS WE ARE GETTING LOCATION BY NETWORK_PROVIDER
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location l) {
        // HERE YOU WILL GET THE LATEST LOCATION AND WILL BE UPDATING WHENEVER YOU CHANGE YOUR LOCATION. 
    }
}
```

Comment: This code updated the location by interval and meter. I need to update the location while the user location changed

Comment: @Karthick You can set the distance to shorter value or time to shorter value or both. This is the only way to get updated of current location. You cannot get the details only when you change your location. You need to keep checking your location.

Comment: Thanks for the update. How can I achieve this in background service. Now, I am searching for background location update. Please guide me.

Comment: Just paste this in you class. It will run in background. And whatever you want to do whenever the location is changed, do it in the `onLocatioUpdate` method.

Comment: Or: keep this class and use an interface to get the updates in your class

Comment: No, after existing the app, the location update is never called.